# string to byte array and array of bytes to file

Tags: arrays, string, delphi, file, binary

I need to implement in Delphi 2006 an algoritm that work in .net

Basicaly I need to do the next steps:

1. Create an XML and validate aganist the XSD
2. Serialize the XML string into an array of bytes UTF-8 encoded and compress it with zip
3. The compressed info must be stored again into a array of bytes using base256 format
4. Create an image using Datamatrix 2D BarCode from this array of bytes and put this image on a report

For step 1, I create the XML using NativeXML library that work ok. In this library exist a metod SaveToBinaryFile but don't work ok. In my tests I used this function to create a binary file.
I was forced to use a binary file becouse my Zip component work only with files not with strings or aray of bytes from memory.

I compressed this binary file with the Zip component and loaded this compresed file into a blob file.
At the moment when I need to create the DataMatrix image I load this blob file into an ansistring and I create the image.

After many tests I found that my fault is when I save my XML into the  binary file.
Now I need to found another way to save my xml (utf-8) string to a binarry file.
Please sorry for my english.
Can anyone help me?

Comment: You can omit the step of converting to binary completely. When you store the file with TNativeXML.SaveToFile it is already UTF-8 encoded unless you didn't specify another encoding.

Comment: yes but the result is not ok. The DataMatrix image can't be converted again to xml from app that are created with other languages

Comment: when I use SavetoBinaryfile some parts of the XML can be obtained from the DataMatrix image.

Comment: The built-in zip component can save to a stream rather than a file

Comment: As for the details of solving your problem, it's pretty much impossible for us to help without you telling us some details. At the moment we have "After many tests I found that my fault is when I save my XML into the binary file" and that's really not anywhere close to enough detail.

Comment: but my problem isn't when I save the zip file. The zip file is saved ok and is loaded on the blob field ok.

Comment: when I save the xml using SaveToFile method the apps that read the DataMatrix image 'read' (and decompres and ...) a string that certainly is not an XML.

Comment: when I save the xml using the SaveToBinaryFile method then the apps can read a string that have 60% of characters like in the original xml.

Comment: Which version of nativexml are you using?

Comment: 4.01, I tried with 4.02 (where the author said that was corrected the binary part of the library) but I found other errors when I create the XML.

Comment: On this moment I need a way to transform the xml (ut8string) into an array of bytes utf-8 encoded and to write this array of bytes to a file.

Comment: `Stream.WriteBuffer(PAnsiChar(utf8str)^, Length(utf8str))`

Answer (score 0):

```
    procedure CreateXMLBarcodeș
    var
     BinarySize: Integer;
     InputString: utf8string;
     StringAsBytes: array of Byte;
     F : FIle of Byte;
     pTemp : Pointer;


    begin
     InputString := '';
     ADoc := TNativeXml.CreateName(rootName);
     try
       ... //create the XML
       InputString := ADoc.WriteToLocalString; //utf8string
       if InputString > '' then begin
          //serialize the XML string to array of bytes
          BinarySize := (Length(InputString) + 1) * SizeOf(Char);
          SetLength(StringAsBytes, BinarySize);
          Move(InputString[1], StringAsBytes[0], BinarySize);
          //save the array of bytes to file
          AssignFile( F, xmlFilename );
          Rewrite(F);
          try
           BinarySize := Length( StringAsBytes );
           pTemp := @StringAsBytes[0];
           BlockWrite(F, pTemp^, BinarySize );
          finally
           CloseFile( F );
          end;
       end;
       finally
        ADoc.Free;
       end;
     end

    ...
    //in other procedure:
         DataSet1XMLBarCode.LoadFromFile(CreateXMLBarcode);
    ...

    //when I want to create the report
    //create the DataMatrix image
    procedure xyz(Sender: TfrxReportComponent);
    var  AWidth, AHeight: Integer;
     function GetStringFromBlob: AnsiString;
     var BlobStream: TStream;
     begin
      Result := '';
      DataSet.Open;
      BlobStream := DataSet1.
                       CreateBlobStream(DataSet1XMLBarCode, bmRead);
      try
       SetLength(Result, BlobStream.Size);
       BlobStream.Position := 0;
       BlobStream.Read(Result[1], BlobStream.Size);
      finally
       BlobStream.Free;
      end;
      DataSet.Close;
     end;
    begin
     Barcode2D_DataMatrixEcc2001.Locked := True;
     Barcode2D_DataMatrixEcc2001.Barcode := GetStringFromBlob;
     Barcode2D_DataMatrixEcc2001.Module := 1;
     Barcode2D_DataMatrixEcc2001.DrawToSize(AWidth, AHeight);
     with TfrxPictureView(frxReport1.FindObject('Picture1')).Picture.Bitmap do
     begin
      Width := AWidth;
      Height := AHeight;
      Barcode2D_DataMatrixEcc2001.DrawTo(Canvas, 0, 0);
     end;
     Barcode2D_DataMatrixEcc2001.Locked := False;
    end;

    //the code was 'çopied'and adapted from the internet
```

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I founded on the web a procedure that I used to 'serialize' the string and a procedure that I used to save the array of bytes to a file. I combined those procedures and the result was posted here